# Opening csv file in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I tried to open a csv file in jupyter notebook, but it shows error message. And I didn't understand the error message. CSV file and jupyter notebook file is in the same directory. plz check the screenshot to see the error message

[jupyter notebook code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQCoP.png)

[csv file and jupyter notebook file is in same directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcpu2.png)

Comment: You should place code directly in here, and never share screen shots of code. It makes it very difficult to troubleshoot since people cannot copy paste your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem I suppose is in the CSV file looking at the error. Maybe NAs or bad formatted data. Check your CSV for consistency

Comment: I can suggest you anyway to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58200424/5333248 . If not working try encoding='UTF-8' instead. If both don't work, solution could be much harder to find

Answer (score 3):

As others have written it's a bit difficult to understand what exactly is your problem.

But why don't you try something like:

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as table:
    for row in table:
        print(row)
        # do something
```

Or:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=",")
# shows top 10 rows
df.head(10)
# do something
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the in-built `csv` package

```
import csv

with open('my_file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
       print(row)
```

This will print each row as an array of items representing each cell.

However, using Jupyter notebook you should use Pandas to nicely display the csv as a table.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

# Displays top 5 rows
df.head(5)

# Displays whole table
df
```

**Resources**

The csv module implements classes to read and write tabular data in CSV format. It allows programmers to say, “write this data in the format preferred by Excel,” or “read data from this file which was generated by Excel,” without knowing the precise details of the CSV format used by Excel.

> Read More CSV: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

pandas is an open source, BSD-licensed library providing high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools for the Python programming language.

> Read More Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas for csv reading.

```
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.read_csv("AppleStore.csv")
```

You can used head/tail function to see the values. Use dtypes to see the types of all the values. You can check the documentation.